# How to show count from another table?

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle.

Now, I want to show number of employees working in each department,

and number of employees in each department must be less than 2.

But I only show `department_id` and `department_name`

I don't know how to show `count`.

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE 2 > (SELECT COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID)
           FROM EMPLOYEES e
           WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

My output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_NAME 
...           | ...
```

Correct output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_NAME |  COUNT(EMPLOYYE_ID) |
...           | ...             |  ...                |
```

Comment: You say must be less than 2 but your query says greater than ? Which one is correct ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Oops, I made a mistake, it is less than. The bottom output is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (added correction for handling cases of departments without employees)

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, NVL(e2.cnt,0) count
FROM DEPARTMENTS d
LEFT JOIN (select e.department_id, count(*) cnt from employees e group by e.department_id) e2
  ON d.department_id=e2.department_id 
where e2.cnt <2
```

Or, more compact

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(e2.employee_id)
FROM DEPARTMENTS d
LEFT JOIN employees e ON d.department_id=e.department_id 
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
HAVING COUNT(*) <2
```

Comment: This code does not show that if there is no one in a department

Comment: ```d.id``` doesn't work. If I change from ```d.id=e2.department_id ``` to ```d.department_id=e2.department_id```. It works. Thx.